# Unable to execute daemon on boot within init.rc

Tags: android, c, linux, kernel, selinux

I have created a daemon but is unable to run it in my Nexus 5 running on Marshmallow.

Following is the code edited in init.rc

```
on init
    chmod 777 /sbin/check_usb
    chown root root /sbin/check_usb

service disableadb /sbin/check_usb
    class main 
    seclabel u:r:disableadb:s0
```

Following is my entry edited within init.usb.rc such that when an adb connection is detected , my daemon will be executed

```
on property:sys.usb.config=accessory,adb && property:sys.usb.configfs=0
start disableadb
```

I have inserted my check_usb program under /sbin/system and granted chmod 777 access to it.

However I notice that in the dmesg | grep disableadb output, my daemon was unable to be executed with the error as follows:

```
init : cannot setexeccon ('u:r:disableadb:s0') Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1):

This error might be due to sepolicy issue.
Your newly added service might not have correct sepolicy configuration.

Add sepolicy rules for this.
create below files.

Create directory `device/xxx/.../sepolicy/check_usb`

Inside, create file `file_contexts`

```
/sbin/check_usb             u:object_r:disableadb:s0
```

Create file: check_usb.te

```
# check_usb service
type check_usb, domain;
type check_usb_exec, exec_type, file_type;

init_daemon_domain(check_usb)

allow init check_usb:process transition;
```

Add this directory in your BoardConfig.mk

```
BOARD_SEPOLICY_DIRS += device/xxx/.../sepolicy/check_usb
```

Comment: Did this solved your question and issue?